# pythonanywere server module not found error

Tags: python, openpyxl, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I get module not found error in python wsgi even though the requirement is already satisfied in bash console?
Error running WSGI application
2022-08-17 18:33:07,709: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
2022-08-17 18:33:07,709:   File "/var/www/anveshj_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in 
2022-08-17 18:33:07,709:     from index import app
2022-08-17 18:33:07,709:
2022-08-17 18:33:07,709:   File "/home/ANVESHJ/UCT-DASHBOARD/index.py", line 7, in 
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710:     import TOOLCOSTS,FAB,PARTSEARCH,LABORHOURS,Version
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710:
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710:   File "/home/ANVESHJ/apps/./PARTSEARCH.py", line 9, in 
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710:     import openpyxl
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710: ***************************************************
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug:
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2022-08-17 18:33:07,710: ***************************************************

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed the module into the same version of Python/virtualenv that you are using to run your web app.

Comment: that's exactly what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot! I had the module installed globally and it was driving me crazy.